# Create input labels from "for" attribute, without changing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

Having an issue learning JavaScript in a college course.  This is my last project and the problem I am having with the HTML code is creating an input field for a label without an id, it has a "for" element though. It cannot be created with JQuery or JSON.

So the HTML looks something like this:
    <"label for="car">What car do you have? <"span class="required"><"/span><"/label">

So I was thinking I could create the input text field and add it to the DOM:

```
// Create the input field
var firstCar = document.createElement("input");
// Create the type node and store what the field will be text
var newType = document.createTypeNode("text");
// Create a new ID of car and attach it to the input
var newID = document.createIdNode("car")
/* put the created Element within the HTML with ["this determines which label it will be under"]:*/
var position = document.getElementByTagName("label")[1];
// Insert the element into the position
position.appendChild(firstCar);
```

I ran this and it says that TypeNode is not a function in my browser.

Comment: FYI - When an `input` element does not specify the `type` attribute, it defaults to `<input type='text'>`.

Comment: Our webpage changed and this is no longer a requirement.  However, if someone would like to answer this still I would appreciate it to learn more about DOM manipulation.

Thank you Marcus.

Comment: It's *getElement**s**ByTagName*, note the plural Elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you set the `type` and `id`. Try this

```
var firstCar = document.createElement("input");

firstCar.type = "text"; // set the type

firstCar.id = "car";    // set the ID

var position = document.getElementsByTagName("label")[1]; // it should be getElements... not getElement...

position.appendChild(firstCar);
```